# How to trigger a function on specific websites from a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Recently started working with Chrome Extensions. 
I am trying to figure out how I can execute a function on a specific website only.

For instance, I want to show an alert box on Stack Overflow only. I am using Chrome's Declarative Content API for this to match the host.

I haven't been able to find a similar question on SO for this.

My manifest.json file is running the following block of code in the background.

```
'use strict';

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function() {
chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.removeRules(undefined, function() {
    chrome.declarativeContent.onPageChanged.addRules([{
        conditions: [
            new chrome.declarativeContent.PageStateMatcher({
                pageUrl: {
                    hostEquals: 'stackoverflow.com'
                }
            })
        ],
        actions: [new chrome.declarativeContent.SOOnlyFunction()]
    }]);
});
});

function SOOnlyFunction()
{
    alert('On SO');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use [`chrome.declarativeContent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeContent) for anything but what's already built in as actions.

Which is currently specifically `ShowPageAction`, `SetIcon` and <del>`RequestContentScript`</del> (still experimental).

The reason that this can't be easily extended is because `declarativeContent` is implemented in native code as a more efficient alternative to JavaScript event handlers.

*In general, chalk it up as an ambitious but essentially unviable/underdeveloped/abandoned idea from Chrome devs, similar fate to [`declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest).*

---

See [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37099843/934239) for implementation ideas using said JS handlers.

Or alternatively, you can still make it "declarative" by using content scripts [declared in the manifest](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#registration) that will only activate on the predefined domain (as long as you know the domain in advance as a constant). They can then do something themselves or [poke the event/background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple) to do something.

Finally, if your goal is to redirect/block the request, [`webRequest` API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) is the one to look at.

Comment: Oh boy! The last line doesn't make me feel so good, all of a sudden. 
Would you suggest I rather go for Chrome Tabs? 

Though, I've heard it'll choke up my RAM. But again, Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: For what you describe, the best idea is to probably have a content script declared in the manifest, and trigger your logic from there (possibly with messaging if you need your background page to do something). It will generate far less noise than trying to listen to `tabs.onUpdated` and require less permissions (you need the scary `"tabs"` to read the URL)

Comment: Great. I'll go ahead with that.

Answer (score 5):

You Can use the Chrome API to achieve this behaviour:

1. When a new Page is Loaded, you can call

   chrome.tabs.onUpdated

   here you can filter the url
2. and To Create Notifications.

   chrome.notifications.create

In your Manifest add these objects:

```
"permissions": [  "activeTab","tabs","notifications" ],
"background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
}
```

Here is How my background.js looks like.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  if(changeInfo.url != null){

     console.log("onUpdated." + " url is "+changeInfo.url);
     // creates Notification.
    showNotification();

  }

});

function showNotification() {

    chrome.notifications.create( {
      iconUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('img/logo128.png'),
      title: 'Removal required',
      type: 'basic',
      message: 'URL is',
      buttons: [{ title: 'Learn More' }],
      isClickable: true,
      priority: 2,
    }, function() {});

}
```

It is incomplete but you will get the Idea.